# Nhibernate on collection item removed

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Entry{
  ...
  public virtual IsDeleted {get;set;}
  public virtual int MyClsId {get;set;}
  public virtual MyClass MyCls {get;set;}
}

public class MyClass{
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Entry> Entries {get;set;}
}
```

When I remove an item from MyClass.Entries I don't actually want to delete it nor kill the realtion. I just want to set Entry.IsDeleted to true and I still want the Entry to keep myClass'es Id;

```
myClassObj.Entries.Remove(myEntry); // after this line myEntry.MyCls.Id 
                                    // should stay intact. myEntry.IsDeleted 
                                    // should be set to true;
```

How can I do that? I tried with interceptors, but couldn't get it to work.

**edit**

Mappings:

Apart form mapping the fields I use:

```
MyClassMap : ...
{
  HasMany(x => Entries).KeyColumn("MyClsId");
}
```

Comment: how is your mapping for this collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create an additional property in MyClass and this seems to be the only working solution.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Entry> NotDeletedEntries{get{return Entries.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted == false);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you actually want to remove this from the collection, maybe it would make more sense to put a method on `Entry` that's like

```
public void Delete(){
    IsDeleted = true;
}
```

and instead of

```
myClassObj.Entries.Remove(myEntry);
```

do

```
myEntry.Delete();
```

Comment: Thought of that, but if do it this way myClassObj.Entries still contains the deleted item, though it shouldn't. (I'll filter deleted entries with interceptor, but it will only work when I create the object)

Comment: @gisek, in the `get` of the `Entries` property, you could try something like `return _entries.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);`. That way, it's still in the collection for NHibernate, but won't show up when you just call `myClassObj.Entries`

Comment: @valverij this property is virtual. It's overridden by Nhibernate, so whatever I put in there doesn't matter.

Comment: Right, but are you worried about it being seen by NHibernate, or are you worried about it being seen by the rest of your application?

Comment: @valverij I'm not worried at all. Just saying that the code I put in there will never be executed, because Nhibernate will inject it's own.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have to update your entity instead of Delete. Try to change your mapping with

```
// set cascade to all to add/update/delete this childs by parent.
HasMany(x => Entries).KeyColumn("MyClsId").Cascade.All();
```

onde the `MyClass` create a method to update it:

```
public class MyClass{
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Entry> Entries {get;set;}

  public void DeleteEntry(Entry entry)
  {
      entry.IsDelete = true;   
  }
}
```

and when you want to set an `Entry` object to IsDeleted to `true` your call the `DeleteEntry` method passing the object and just persist the `MyClass` instance, the childs will be persisted together.

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(myClassObj);
```

Comment: But I want it gone from the collection (MyClass.Entries). On the next object load it'll be filtered by interceptor, but just after delete it will stay though it shouldn't.

Comment: when you call `session.SaveOrUpdate` passing the MyClass instance, it will update the `MyClass.Entries` collection!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't call SaveOrUpdate. This operation is just a part of a big transaction. (I'm using unit of work)

Comment: But won't if fire a commit automatically? (I don't want a commit at this point)

Comment: No, until you call `transaction.Commit`, it will not be commited to database.

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand your scenario correctly you would like to have a *Delete* action which would at the end:

- keep the relation
- mark the item as `IsDeleted`
- do not keep it in the collection of the parent *(here I am not sure, but if needed, we have the solution below)*

1) To keep the relation we simply won't call delete all the way.

We can introduce a method on the Parent `RemoveEntry`

```
public class MyClass 
{
  public virtual void RemoveEntry(Entry entry) // or by index, name
  {
     // some checks over Entries collection
     entry.IsDeleted = true;
  }
}
```

when the MyClass instance is updated `session.Update(myClass)`, all the entries will be as well

2) To mark it as `IsDeleted`, we will just append cascading (see more here [fluent mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping)

```
MyClassMap : ...
{
  HasMany(x => Entries)
   .KeyColumn("MyClsId")
   .Cascade.All()
}
```

3) To remove that item from a *lazy* load of the Parent children collection, we can append a `where` clause to the collection mapping. See example here: [where clause in the mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2319743/1679310)

```
MyClassMap : ...
{
  HasMany(x => Entries)
    .KeyColumn("MyClsId")
    .Cascade.All()
    .Where("IsDeleted = 0"); // that will load only IsDeleted == false lazily
}
```

More about where clause in documentation: [6.2. Mapping a Collection](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping)

Comment: Where("IsDeleted = 0") works fine if I retrieve the object form database, but what should I do if the object is already retrieved?

Comment: I strongly suggest separation of concern. In one operation you use session to Udpate objects (Entry or MyObject). Then in another (after redierection e.g. in ASP.NET MVC) you do relaod it. That's how it works in many our scenarios. And it works well ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is not to use the entity directy but a DTO which is copy of your entity (with all the collection items). You perform the remove action on the DTO (so the deleted collection item is invisible to the application) and later on when you want to save the entity you just synchronize it with the DTO (for the removed collection item you set the IsDeleted flag to true). A little bit more of work, but it achieves what you want to do.